# Resolving 2 symbols and adding elements in RecyclerView/CardView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, cardview

Im following [this tutorial](https://knowledgecollisions.wordpress.com/2016/03/29/using-recyclerview-and-cardview-in-your-android-app/), and I followed the directions carefully, but I ran into a few problems. In my ItemView constructor, cardview and photo are "symbols that cannot be resolved":

```
ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            cover = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        }
```

Here is the entire adapter class:

```
package com.example.aaronpries.myfinal;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemAdapter.ItemViewHolder>{

    private Context context;
    private List<Item> books;



    ItemAdapter(List<Item> books){
        this.books = books;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return books.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_cal, viewGroup, false);
        ItemViewHolder bvh = new ItemViewHolder(v);
        return bvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder bookViewHolder, int i) {

        bookViewHolder.title.setText(books.get(i).text);
        bookViewHolder.cover.setImageResource(books.get(i).imgID);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    public static class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        TextView title;
        ImageView cover;



        ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardview);
            title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            cover = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        }
    }

}
```

This is my item class:

```
package com.example.aaronpries.myfinal;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Item implements Serializable{

    public int id;

    public String text;

    public int imgID;
}
```

Here is the recyclerview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Activity xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cardview"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the Activity class:

```
public class CalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   String[] events = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};

    Context context = this;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cal);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'm trying to follow a few different tutorials on how to get this a RecyclerView working, but most of them don't show completed code at the end, and since I'm so new, I sometime have a hard time following. I also want to add an image and title text to the RecyclerView, so if you have suggestions on that I'd appreciate it. Do I just do Item.add("text",imgID) over and over again to populate the data?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have figured out the symbols part. I think I didn't use the android:id="photo" instead of android:id="@+id/photo". Not sure what the difference is, but I think that helped.

Comment: `@+id/photo` will make it possible for you to find `R.id.photo` or reference within a layout. `android:id` is not a required attribute, though

Comment: Also, when you have `layout_toRightOf="@+id/photo"`, it should really just be `layout_toRightOf="@id/photo"`. No plus